# how to reject a string with # or ? using regex python

Tags: python, regex

I want to validate my string to check whether is valid. The string is valid if it contains `(_,-,alphanumerics)` excluding any other special character.

I am using the regular expression below, but if the string contains `#` or `?` at the end of the string, it is considered valid instead of throwing an error of invalid string.

```
def is_valid_id(id_):
    """Check if id is valid"""
    return re.match(r'^[\-a-zA-Z0-9_]+\Z', id_)
```

I expect the string to be invalid if it contains any special character at the end of the string except`(_,-)`

Comment: Your regex [does not match strings ending with these chars](https://regex101.com/r/XD7mVo/1).

Comment: Can you provide an example of a string that is considered valid despite ending with "#" or "?"? I tried `print(is_valid_id("foo#"))` and it printed `None`, which means it's invalid, right? I can't replicate your problem.

Comment: If you're asking "why is `re.match` not throwing an invalid string exception when I give it a string that fails to match?", that's just how re.match works. It doesn't crash when it fails to match, it merely returns None.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without regexps, by using only [string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html?highlight=string#module-string) module and [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=all#all) function:

```
import string
possible_chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '_-'
a = 'lwngjgeiunekrgn?'
all(char in possible_chars for char in a)
```

> `False`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `$`.

```
return re.match(r'^[\-a-zA-Z0-9_]+$', id_)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? Why would replacing "\Z" with "$" do anything? They both match the end of the string, don't they?

Comment: `\Z` matches *only* the end of the string, while `$` could match before a trailing newline (or before any newline when using the `MULTILINE` flag). In this case, the differences would appear to be irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I don't know the difference between usage of "\z", "\Z" and "$". I just thought of replacing it with "$" would work fine. But now, I knew that it's wrong.